# Convert an IndexPath array to a UIImage array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I am trying to create an array of images/videos that are selected from a collection view and store them using Core Data. I have an array of the selected cells and it is dynamic because it allows for the user to add or subtract images to the array by selecting or deselecting the cell. My code currently uses IndexPath to accomplish this but I believe I need to convert it to an UIImage array so that I can add it to Core Data [based on another solution I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182883/4035833). So how do I convert the selectedCells array below to a UIImage array?

```
var selectedCells: [IndexPath] = []

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? ImageCell {
      selectedCells.append(indexPath)
      cell.index = selectedCells.count
  }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  guard let idx = selectedCells.firstIndex(of: indexPath) else { return }
  selectedCells.remove(at: idx)
  let curSelected: [IndexPath] = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems ?? []
  collectionView.reloadData()
  let saveY = collectionView.contentOffset.y
  collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
      curSelected.forEach { pth in
          collectionView.selectItem(at: pth, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
      }
  }, completion: { _ in
      collectionView.contentOffset.y = saveY
  })
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The reason I decided to use Core Data is because the users will need to be able to edit the images but if they stop in the middle of it and come back the users progress needs to be saved. If they close the app the progress will be lost. I no longer think I need to store the image itself, just a reference to the the image in the library. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You dont even need to hold your own selectedCells, there is a property called "indexPathsForSelectedItems" for this purpose. You are overcomplicating things with your reload strategy.

Then use those indexpaths to access your datasource like you do in cellForRow(at: indexPath).
So lets say you have a helper called func object(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> YourObjectModel
then you can "convert" the indexpath array using array's map functionality.

Additionally, an image should not end up being stored in coredata ... only a reference to it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand all of your response. I am using "indexPathsForSelectedItems" (see "let curSelected: [IndexPath]" line). I am also using the reload strategy so that so that when a user deselects an item the cells will be renumbered. For example if they select "1, 2, 3, 4" and then deselect "2" the cells will be renumbered to "1, 2, 3" and not "1, 3, 4". Maybe I am missing something. Can you show a solution/example?